# GitHub Cache with Maven project in subdirectory

Tags: maven, github, github-actions

I had the following configuration of my GH Action workflow of a simple Maven project.

```yaml
name: Java CI

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11
      - name: Cache Maven repository
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.m2/repository
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-maven-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-maven-
      - name: Verify with Maven
        run: mvn -B -e -ff clean verify
```

Everything used to work, till I move the Maven project into a `code` subdirectory:

```yaml
name: Java CI

on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - code/**
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 11
      - name: Cache Maven repository
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.m2/repository
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-maven-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-maven-
      - name: Verify with Maven
        run: mvn -B -e -ff clean verify --file code/pom.xml
```

Now in the log I see the cache step says `Cache not found for input keys: Linux-maven-xxxxxxx, Linux-maven-`.

Does anyone know why the cache is not working with the project in a subdirectory?
Thanks.

Comment: Why have you moved into a sub directory? Usually the pom file is in the root of the project?... Furthermore why are you reacting on `paths:  - code/**..`?

Comment: The reason for moving it into the subdirectory because the root contains other resources, like (AWS) CDK, K8S, etc. And because the job is just to run the maven tests, it's conditional on changes in `code` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you are not overriding `localRepository` in your settings.yaml file. Maven will use default local repository `~/.m2/repository` no matter where you put your project directory.

As a test, you can try to change the maven repository path for artifacts if you are not currently overriding the default local maven repo directory

Add following env variable to your workflow before the jobs start

```
  env: 
     MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=${{ github.workspace }}/repository"
```

Then call cache action with the following

```
  - name: Cache Maven repository
    uses: actions/cache@v2
    with:
      path: "${{ github.workspace }}/repository"
      key: ${{ runner.os }}-maven-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
      restore-keys: |
        ${{ runner.os }}-maven-
```